# How to fix this SQL query? I couldn't find a solution

Tags: sql, sql-server, syntax-error

I'm trying to execute this query but it doesn't work and an error message appears.

```
SELECT 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.ACCNUM_0, 
    CASE
       WHEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.SNS_0 < 0
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.RVS_0 <> 3
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVC"
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVE"
            AND LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.PAYTYP_0 = "CCHQT"
            AND LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.STA_0 < 5
          THEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.AMTLOC_0 * 1
       WHEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.SNS_0 < 0
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.RVS_0 <> 3
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVC"
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVE"
            AND LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.PAYTYP_0 = "CTRT"
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.DUDDAT_0 = GETDATE()
          THEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.AMTLOC_0 * 1
    END AS ENC_NC
FROM 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRY, LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD, LAMACOM.PAYMENTH
WHERE
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.TYP_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.NUM_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0
    LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.BPRVCR_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0
```

and here it is the problem

> Microsoft SQL: syntax incorrecte vers 'LAMACOM'.

I couldn't define from which table the problem comes from.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 25 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I used also this syntax and the problem still presist FROM LAMACOM.GACCENTRY
inner join LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD on 
LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.TYP_0 =LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 
LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.NUM_0 =LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0

inner join LAMACOM.PAYMENTH on 
LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.BPRVCR_0= LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to put AND or OR condition in WHERE clause

```
SELECT 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.ACCNUM_0, 
    CASE
       WHEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.SNS_0 < 0
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.RVS_0 <> 3
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVC"
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVE"
            AND LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.PAYTYP_0 = "CCHQT"
            AND LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.STA_0 < 5
          THEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.AMTLOC_0 * 1
       WHEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.SNS_0 < 0
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.RVS_0 <> 3
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVC"
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 <> "AVE"
            AND LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.PAYTYP_0 = "CTRT"
            AND LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.DUDDAT_0 = GETDATE()
          THEN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.AMTLOC_0 * 1
    END AS ENC_NC
FROM 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRY, LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD, LAMACOM.PAYMENTH
WHERE
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.TYP_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 AND
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.NUM_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0 AND 
    LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.BPRVCR_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0
```

To avoid these issues in future, you can parse the query to know the issue line or message 
user

> CTRL +F5

or press check icon after selecting the query

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Your `WHERE` contains 3 conditions, but the conditions need to be separated, most likely by `AND`:

```
FROM 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRY, LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD, LAMACOM.PAYMENTH
WHERE
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.TYP_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 AND
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.NUM_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0 AND
    LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.BPRVCR_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0
```

Or if you follow best practices and use `JOIN`s:

```
FROM LAMACOM.GACCENTRY
JOIN LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD ON LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.TYP_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0
JOIN LAMACOM.PAYMENTH   ON LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.BPRVCR_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0
```

This does not need a `WHERE`, unless you want to impose further conditions (and then: don't forget the `AND`!)

Answer (score 0):

You have `]` character on lines 10 and 14 which seems like a typo.

Comment: No i deleted the ] caracter but the problem still presist

Comment: The conditions in WHERE clause are not joined (missing AND/OR)

Answer (score 0):

You can use INNER JOIN

```
SELECT 
    ....
FROM 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRY
INNER JOIN 
    LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD ON LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.TYP_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0
INNER JOIN 
    LAMACOM.PAYMENTH ON LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.BPRVCR_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0
```

Answer (score 0):

You must use AND after each WHERE clusure.

```
WHERE
LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.TYP_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.TYP_0 AND
LAMACOM.GACCENTRYD.NUM_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0 AND 
LAMACOM.PAYMENTH.BPRVCR_0 = LAMACOM.GACCENTRY.NUM_0
```